# INDEX MATCH multiple occurrences

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create conditional formatting which highlights all rows with processes which has been already "solved".

FORMULA PURPOSE: highlight all rows with processes which has been already "solved".

PROBLEM: I am struggling with INDEX MATCH formula and multiple occurrences.

To do this I created two helper columns:
- First is to concatenate two records what is not important in our case)
- second formula is supposed to return TRUE or FALSE when any of duplicates has been marked as solved.

Comment: What formula have you tried? What does your data look like? Are you getting an error? Please post the information in the question, rather than an attached Excel file (which many people won't download, due to security risks).

Comment: You mean the Formula is needed to write True when one of the duplicates is solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try selecting ColumnsA:D and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1,$D:$D,"solved")>0
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: Such a pretty and elegant solution! Thank you!